# Integer value comparing not working expected

Tags: mysql

I am completely new to MySql.

Why if block is not executed in snippet below ?

```
declare row_exist int;
select count(id) into row_exist from country  where name='japan';

if(row_exist = 1) then
   signal sqlstate '45000'
   set message_text = 'Error = Duplicate country found !';
end if;
```

and this works

```
declare row_exist int;
select count(id) into row_exist from country  where name='japan';

if(row_exist >= 0) then
   signal sqlstate '45000'
   set message_text = 'Error = Duplicate country found !';
end if;
```

There is only one entry for 'japan'.

Comment: You may need `GROUP BY` on the query.

Comment: @JayF1: What are you talking about? NO!

Comment: it sounds like a case of using a stored procedure when all you reallyl need is a unique constraint.

Comment: @e4c5 Sicilian ;) . I am using StoredProcedure to insert values, and checking it record already exist. Why  '= 1' not working.

Comment: Hello fellow chess, player. You don't need to do this. The more robust approach is to create a unique constraint on the column in question.

Comment: @e4c5 and how to handle this on the client side to inform user.

Comment: depends on the programming language you are using. YOu seem to already have the code to handle the exception raised in your stored procedure. Change that to handle the unique constraint violation exception.

Comment: have you checked row_exists value, although there is only one 'japan' record?